# Why the focus of react-select always moves to the first element?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

Why the focus of react-select always moves to the first element even if the cursor is in another option?

I'm currently using version "react-select": "^4.3.0",

```
      <Select 
      defaultValue={[options[4], options[5]]}
      name="clothes"
      options={options}
      isMulti
      onChange={handleChange}
      />
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This may be because the component is re-rendering unnecessarily.  I had this happen when I accidentally omitted the dependency in a useEffect that was loading the options.